# Apache: proxy an internal URL using regex

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have a few servlets listening on internal ports which are not accessible from outside. I use Apache's `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives to serve them securely from port 443:

```
ProxyPass         /media http://localhost:9002/
ProxyPassReverse  /media http://localhost:9002/
```

This works fine - `https://example.com/media` is served from `http://localhost:9002/`.

The problem happens when the URL has a varying part. For example:

`https://example.com/image/IMAGE_NAME_1` should be served from `http://localhost:9002/image/IMAGE_NAME_1`.

And `https://example.com/image/IMAGE_NAME_2` should be served from `http://localhost:9002/image/IMAGE_NAME_1`.

I've tried some variations, including:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule   ^/image/(.*)$  http://localhost:9002/image/$1 [L,PT]
ProxyPass         /image/ http://localhost:9002/image
ProxyPassReverse  /image/ http://localhost:9002/image
```

But this configuration results in `Bad Request` in the browser and

```
Invalid URI in request GET /image/1 HTTP/1.1
```

In the logs.

**How do I proxy internal servlets where the URL has a varying part?**

Comment: I only see URLs, no parameters.

Comment: `IMAGE_NAME` is a parameter, because it varies between calls. Am I using the term incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, it appears so. There's no query string on any of these URLs, and that's where one would pass parameters.

Comment: Of course, my bad. Parameters in URL context has that meaning. Regex matching would be a better description. Rewriting my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use `ProxyPassMatch` instead:

```
ProxyPassMatch    ^/media http://localhost:9002/(.*)
ProxyPassReverse  ^/media http://localhost:9002/(.*)
```

Find further details in the [Apache online documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch).